# CsvReaderException was unhandled

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I keep running into this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.CsvReaderException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll
>
> Additional information: No properties are mapped for type 'RPS_String_Parse.Program+FormattedRow'.

But I believe I am following [the documentation](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) correctly. After referencing the "getting started" portion i implemented this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
    var records = csv.GetRecords<FormattedRow>();
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(record.Address1);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and my class:

```
public class FormattedRow
{
        public string IDOrderAlpha;
        public string IDOrder;
        public string AddressCompany;
        public string Address1;
        public string Address2;
        public string AddressCity;
        public string AddressState;
        public string AddressZip;
        public string AddressCountry;
        public string ShipMethod;
        public string ContactEmail;
        public string ContactName;
        public string ServiceRep;
        public string CustomerPuchaseOrder;
}
```

I feel like this should work, because the documentation states:

> Auto Mapping
>
> If you don't supply a mapping file, auto mapping will be
>   used. Auto mapping will map the properties in your class in the order
>   they appear in. If the property is a custom class, it recursively maps
>   the properties from that class in the order they appear in. If the
>   auto mapper hits a circular reference, it will stop going down that
>   reference branch

**What am I missing?**

Comment: I'm running in to the same error but I have the {get; set;). Did you have to do anything else to fix the problem?

Comment: Just making it a property worked for me, however it must be a public property. If all the properties are marked as internal or private it will result in the same error message.

Comment: In my experience, the AutoMapper seems to require the CSV headers to match the field names, rather than mapping by index.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation states that it will map to `Properties`. Your class has `Fields`. Make this change:

```
public class FormattedRow
{
    public string IDOrderAlpha { get; set; }
    // add { get; set; } for all
}
```

This will change your fields to "auto properties".

Answer (score 1):

**You need to set the configuration options for mapping:**

```
var generatedMap = csv.Configuration.AutoMap<MyClass>();
```

So it appears you need to tell it to automap.  I've never used this library before.

**Edit:**  Jon B nailed it.